# Using Regex to find if the string is inside the array and replace it + PHP

Tags: php, regex

```
$restricted_images = array(
    "http://api.tweetmeme.com/imagebutton.gif",
    "http://stats.wordpress.com",
    "http://entrepreneur.com.feedsportal.com/",
    "http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net"
);
```

This are the list of images that I want to know if a certain string has that kind of string.

For example:

```
$string = "http://api.tweetmeme.com/imagebutton.gif/elson/test/1231adfa/".
```

Since `"http://api.tweetmeme.com/imagebutton.gif"` is in the `$restricted_images` array and it is also a string inside the variable `$string`, it will replace the `$string` variable into just a word `"replace".`

Do you have any idea how to do that one? I'm not a master of RegEx, so any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why regex?

```
$restricted_images = array(
    "http://api.tweetmeme.com/imagebutton.gif",
    "http://stats.wordpress.com",
    "http://entrepreneur.com.feedsportal.com/",
    "http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net"
);

$string = "http://api.tweetmeme.com/imagebutton.gif/elson/test/1231adfa/";
$restrict = false;
foreach($restricted_images as $restricted_image){
    if(strpos($string,$restricted_image)>-1){
        $restrict = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($restrict) $string = "replace";
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help

```
foreach ($restricted_images as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($string, $value) >= 0){
        $string = 'replace';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex because you're looking for direct string matches.

You can try this:

```
foreach ($restricted_images as $url) // Iterate through each restricted URL.
{
    if (strpos($string, $url) !== false) // See if the restricted URL substring exists in the string you're trying to check.
    {
        $string = 'replace'; // Reset the value of variable $string.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use regex'es for this.

```
$test = "http://api.tweetmeme.com/imagebutton.gif/elson/test/1231adfa/";
foreach($restricted_images as $restricted) {
    if (substr_count($test, $restricted)) {
        $test = 'FORBIDDEN';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Prepare the $restricted_images array for use by preg_replace()
$func = function($value)
{
    return '/'.preg_quote($value).'/';
}
$restricted_images = array_map($func, $restricted_images);

$string = preg_replace($restricted_images, 'replace', $string);
```

Edit:

If you decide that you don't need to use regular expressions (which is not really needed with your example), here's a better example then all of those `foreach()` answers:

```
$string = str_replace($restricted_images, 'replace', $string);
```